# Ubuntu 21.04 and 20.04 randomly reboots on my PC

Tags: 20.04, crash, reboot

My PC with installed Ubuntu 20.04 keeps rebooting.

Before 20.04 LTS I had Ubuntu 21.04, which had the same issue, which is why I decided to install previous version.

I tried to ground it in the office. It didn't help. One day, I even took it home from the office, I connected it at home with  another power cable. It still rebooted several times. So, probably, it is not static electricity causing reboots.

I tried to run it without video card. It kept rebooting.

I inserted RAMs into different sockets. It kept rebooting.

I plugged my PC into UPS. The same.

I brought it to the service. They tested my PC for two days. They experienced same problem. Their checked hardware, said that it was ok. Installed windows on the same SSD, and there was no reboots with it. Then they somehow upgraded my Ubuntu. I am not sure what they did. But after that, they say, they did not experienced rebooting. However, when I brought it to the office it rebooted again.

I have 32 Gb of RAM, I had 2 Gb of swap which I increased an hour ago to 16 Gb, but it didn't solve problem with reboots. I have a NVIDIA P106-100 graphic card with 6Gb memory.

Time between reboots is random it can be 2 minutes or 12 hours. I am newbie in Linux, so, please, tell me what commands I should execute to provide you with needed information. Thanks for your help and time!

EDIT: Thanks to everyone! After replacement of motherboard the problem gone.

Comment: "*Their checked hardware, said that it was ok. Installed windows on the same SSD, and there was no reboots with it.*" -- do not use that service again. Because your hardware is clearly NOT ok. A reboot from software requires a specific set of triggers to the BIOS; Ubuntu simply cannot random-reboot without the event and reason  being logged...but your motherboard and BIOS can.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks for advice! Could you tell me what should I check in BIOS to understand if the problem is there. Also, I didn't find anything worrisome in logs. Though, I am not proficient in reading them and extract clues from there, so I might have easily missed something important.

Answer (score 4):

Stop thrashing! Diagnosis must precede Solution.

After a "sudden shutdown", aka "system crash", and reboot, or an intentional reboot, the terminal  command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's logs. If there is no hint there, suspect power/ overheating.

Overheating is most likely caused by dust. Power down your system. Unblock your fans and vents, clean out the dust. Ensure air circulation. Dust that coats heat exchangers and chips is a good insulator,  and bad for cooling. Don't disassemble your computer until you have downloaded the manufacturer's  manual, and researched how-to-clean. Make this information available for when your computer isn't (paper, other computer) **Don't use water.**

Read `man journalctl` to see how to extract information from the logs.

You can find how I make use of `journalctl` easier at `https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator`.

Comment: Thanks for advice! I doubt that overheating is a problem, since there is little dust inside a corpus. Psensor shows that hardware temperature is no more than 35 degrees. I will be looking at journalctl output for sometime, maybe I will find something there. Now I see these: 
`cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed 
cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed 
Failed to register: Unable to acquire bus name 'org.gnome.Nautilus'`